# The DTD for the following XML gives error

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

```
At a school, there are many classes and the following elements are identified.
```

- There is a principal, he has name, age and address
- Every class got a class teacher
- Each class teacher holds the following information

  - Class_number
  - Teacher_Details
  - Number_of_students
- Teacher_details section includes the following information

  - Teacher_name
  - DoB

  The question is DTD document for the above information

I created the XML and the DTD using VS 2008. But there is an error in the first line of DTD.

```
<!DOCTYPE school [
  <!ELEMENT school (principal|ClassTeacher)*>
  <!ELEMENT principal (name,age,address)>
  <!ELEMENT name    (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT age     (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT address  (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT ClassTeacher (cno,td*,nos)>
  <!ELEMENT cno   (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT td (name,dob)>
  <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT dob (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT nos (#PCDATA)>
]>

<school>
  <principal>
    <name>sdasd</name>
    <age>456</age>
    <address>jhkh</address>
  </principal>

  <ClassTeacher>
    <cno>456</cno>
    <td>
      <name>gyj</name>
      <dob>fgd</dob>
    </td>
    <nos>45</nos>
  </ClassTeacher>
</school>
```

[image: The DTD and XML with error in 1st line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Main Problem

The primary issue is that you declare `name` twice. Remove one of the declarations to fix the immediate error.

## Additional Problem

```
<!ELEMENT school (principal|ClassTeacher)*>
```

This is a "choice list" of an "element content" declaration, which means `school` can have either multiple `principal` or multiple `ClassTeacher` children but not both.  See [Element Type Declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition#Element_type_declarations).

Try

```
<!ELEMENT school (principal, ClassTeacher*)>
```

This will require that `principal` is the first element, followed by any number (including zero) of `ClassTeacher` elements.

Comment: Did you remove the duplicate definition? It works for me in Oxygen/XML.